# NgRx How to launch a feature module from another module

Tags: ngrx

I have three modules: AppModule, ModuleX, ModuleY.
In ModuleX I get and store data with NgRx but it only does so If I route to one of the components of ModuleX's and trigger OnInit lifecycle hook. I need to access that data in ModuleY.
Is there any way to do that,can I globally access to data that stored in the state from anywhere?

Comment: I am assuming that the mentioned modules are Angular Modules (NOT NGRX Feature Modules) then you can access that data in ModuleY only after ModuleX's component is rendered. You need to change your design to fetch that data some where in app.component so that the data is available in all modules.

Comment: This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all **relevant** content. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.